# Can not create a complete android app using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I have just reviewed a lot of questions to be sure that's my question is not duplicated. After installing `Android SDK`, `JDK`, `Eclipse`, `ADT` plugin. I started to create an android project, but I think I can not create any project probably. These are the files I get:

[image]

Also, when I try to run the app, I got `Could not find LSCP.apk!`. As I told you guys, I reviewed a lot of questions talk about this problem, but without any helping.

Comment: Try this.. go to Project -> clean.. and then close all the .java files and other files and restart eclipse..

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something like that when creating a project from existing source.  You can fix it-  go into the project properties to the android build path.  Get rid of everything in there.  Then readd your src and gen folders to it, and readd your android jar file from the SDK.  In the ordering screen, make sure that the android jar comes before the other two.  While you're in there, make sure the Java compiler is set to 1.6.  Do this and it should refactor itself and lose the grayed out look and finally compile (may need to do a clean first).

Comment: I found that the ADT plugin need the Android support library v8 and I can not find it in the manager. Only there's the Android support library v11. So how can I install it?

Answer (score 0):

See if the following link helps you:

http://peepaal.org/profiles/blogs/getting-started-with-android

if you have followed these steps..try the next step in the same tutorial...